# countApprox() initialValue always return the same bounds

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have a method for calculating and displaying approx number of rows in a dataframe:

```
public static void countApprox(String csvPath, long timeout, double confidence) {
        Dataset<Row> table = spark.read().csv(csvPath);
        final PartialResult<BoundedDouble> result = table.javaRDD().countApprox(timeout, confidence);
        System.out.println("init mean value: " + result.initialValue().mean()); //is always 0
        System.out.println("init value high: " + result.initialValue().high());  //is always infinity
        System.out.println("init value low: " + result.initialValue().low());   //is always 0
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("calculating final values...");
                long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("final value high: " + result.getFinalValue().high()); 
                System.out.println("final value low: " + result.getFinalValue().low());
                double timeTaken = (System.currentTimeMillis() - initTime)/1000.0;
                System.out.println("time taken: " + timeTaken + " second(s)");
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

The problem is, no matter what parameters I provide for timeout and confidence (timeout value less than actual time taken to count), the results for initialValue low, mean and high values are always same: (0.0, 0.0, infinity).
Any help in figuring out what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Timeout is in milliseconds, what values have you tried?

Comment: any timeout value less than the time taken to actually count the number of rows always returns the same result. For example, if time taken to count number of rows is 15000L ms, any value less than 15000 yields the same result. any value more than or equal to 15000 yields the actual count value, which is the same for all, initial and final highs, lows and means.